# SQL find teacher courses query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get teacher `FIRSTNAME`, `LASTNAME` and count of courses he got. Oracle database. `CLASS` table has columns: `CLASSID`, `TEACHERID`, `CLASSNAME` Current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, COUNT(TEACHERID)
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PERSONID = T.TEACHERID 
INNER JOIN CLASS C ON T.TEACHERID = C.TEACHERID
WHERE T.TEACHERID = C.TEACHERID;
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `WHERE T.TEACHERID = C.TEACHERID` is redundant because it's already in your `INNER JOIN` predicate.

Comment: Answer was correct

Comment: Oracle != MySQL, please use correct tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a GroupBy:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, COUNT(T.TEACHERID)
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PERSONID = T.TEACHERID 
INNER JOIN CLASS C ON T.TEACHERID = C.TEACHERID
GROUP BY LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME
```

By the way, I initially deleted this answer because it's not a good way to do the grouping.  I'd instead prefer grouping by `TEACHERID`, then joining back to get the names, rather than grouping by names.

I think this is a better approach:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, C.NUMCLASSES
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PERSONID = T.TEACHERID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TEACHERID, COUNT(CLASSID) AS NUMCLASSES FROM CLASS GROUP BY TEACHERID) C
ON C.TEACHERID=T.TEACHERID
```

Comment: @TeodorKolev I've added a second way to do the join, using a subquery.  The first method groups by names, which is going to be a problem if two teachers share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the GROUP BY clause after the WHERE clause

> GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME --all the selected columns except those in aggregate functions such as COUNT

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 
(select COUNT(C.TEACHERID) form CLASS C ON T.TEACHERID = C.TEACHERID)
as COURSECOUNT
FROM PERSON 
INNER JOIN TEACHER T ON PERSON.PERSONID = T.TEACHERID
```